# How to convert Webex' WRF to any other video format?

Tags: video-conversion, conferencing, webex

I've recorded a Webex WRF screencast and I'd like to convert it to WMV or AVI or something.
The Webex Editor keeps saying it needs Windows Media Player 9.

Is there any other way to convert WRF?

Answer (score 1):

The [official player](http://www.webex.com/play-webex-recording.html) from the WebEx site supports transcoding to WMV, SWF (and on my Win7 version, MP4; although the page does not list that). WebEx KB offers an article (http://kb.webex.com/WBX28158) on how to use the tool for transcoding, but I doubt one would need to read it.

There is also a [WebEx Recording Editor](http://kb.webex.com/WBX20856), though I have no experience using it.

Comment: The player only converts ARF not WRF.  The WebEx Recording Editor can convert WRF to WMV though.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody get stuck with conversion from ARF to MP4 that requires the login. For the Site URL, I used `https://meetings.webex.com/collabs/`.