# How to download video from a recorded webex session?

Tags: video, download, recording, webex

I have a link to recorded webex webinar, I wish to download the video and convert into different format. How should I go about the downloading the recorded webex video ?
Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert Webex' WRF to any other video format?](http://superuser.com/questions/189415/how-to-convert-webex-wrf-to-any-other-video-format), because you said you want to "convert it into different format"

Comment: yes, but first I need to download it, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 11):

I used Process Monitor to locate temp files.
Search for nbrplay.exe, operations WriteFile
Temp files are located in %TEMP% in folder named something like 29784192

Video is in DAT
SOund is in WAV

I don't know how to open DAT file though.

Answer (score 4):

[It seems that](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/289252-Downloading-WebEx-streaming-%28-wrf-files%29) while watching a Webinar, there are temporary files created in your Temporary Folder.

You'd have to go to the Temp folder, arrange the items by modification date, and look for the ones created when you visit the Webinar site and start playing. If you're lucky, you'll find several files, including the biggest one, which is probably a video.

It'll probably not have the right extension, but a rename might do, or, depending on the contents, directly trying to open it with VLC. You'd have to inspect the file for any hints towards which video codec and container is used, and then try the appropriate extension (e.g. `mp4` or `avi`).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of downloading a WebEx, what you can do is use the WebEx player to stream the video to your PC and then record it using the latest version of SnagIt.  Then you can save the file as an MP4 to your hard disk.

SnagIt can record both audio and video in addition to still screenshots.

Answer (score 3):

The is a comprehensive guide on downloading in proprietary format (arf), and then converting to wmv on the Webex website, both for owners (host through managing interface) and viewers (non-host through URL link)
http://support.webex.com/support/documentation/help/index.htm#9398.htm

Comment: the link seems broken.

Answer (score 1):

While streaming the recording, go to *%appdata%\Local\Temp*

You will see a folder that has an ID number (the ID can be found in the small window that opens when you click the recording in Webex to open the Webex Player).

After that let it stream and don't close the player, enter that folder with IDs and you will find everything you need: some .wav for sound and .dat for videos, sometimes they are combined.